# Is there a way to close the connection after using firebase.initializeApp() with Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, discord.js

I'm attempting to make a Discord.js command that uploads data to Cloud Firestore. It works, just if I attempt to reuse the command it reruns the `firebase.initializeApp()` line, which throws an error. Is there any way to disconnect after I have uploaded the data?

Comment: It's not clear at all here what you're trying to do or what isn't working the way you expect.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to disconnect - the time and processing cycle cost of .initializeApp() is prohibitive unless these calls are quite rare.

There are a few of valid approaches:

=> Keep a state value that indicates that the app is already initialized

=> initialize firebase at a "higher point" in your code to avoid reloading the module

=> I believe you can actually "ask" firebase if there is a running app, in which case don't re-initialize (`const app = firebase.app()`)

If for some reason you *do* need to remove a firebase app instance:

```
const app = firebase.app(); //retrieves the default instance
app.delete()
  .then(function() {
    console.log("App deleted successfully");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting app:", error);
  });
```

Comment: For asking if the app is running, how would the if statement look?
`if (!firebase.app()) {
    await firebase,initializeApp()
} else {
    const db = firebase.app()
}`
Would it look similar to this? I'm sorry for that awful formatting, I can throw it in a pastebin if that's easier to read.

Comment: I would do !firebase.app().name, but yes, essentially that.  Better if you separate the module loading the needed functions from the initialization - ES6 modules are pretty good at NOT re-running code just to get a function/variable, but I don't know discord.js.  btw, according to documentation, the default name is "[DEFAULT]" https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App